# iphone : embed a fully integrated customized (Google) map in a native app

Tags: iphone, google-maps, customization, integrated

1. Is it possible to send GPS coordinates, a name and hyperlink to a kind of Google map API so that it shows a map, some places with a name and whenever a user clicks on a place would go to a URL?
2. If so, is it possible to attach this map as a view so that a user can make use of the navigator bar of the native application at any time?

If it is possible, how could it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google:

http://www.invasivecode.com/2009/07/adding-maps-to-your-iphone-app-mapkit/
http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/